# How can I remove the rows that matches from one Excel column with another Excel file? With VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Hi and thanks for your help.

I've two Excel files, lets call them Excel 1 (active one), and Excel 2 (which I just need to compare if there's duplicates).
I want to remove the matches from Excel 1 that are found in Excel 2. Only deleting the matches from Excel 1, and keeping the Excel 2 intact.

I normally do this process with a *Vlookup* then delete the matches.
[Example][1]: `=VLOOKUP(C2,'[End Use Screening Log.xlsb]EUS Log'!$A:$A,1,0))`

This is the macro code produced after the Vlookup:

```
 Sub Testing()
'
' Testing Macro
'
'
    Workbooks.Open Filename:= _
        "Z:\Customer Screening\End User Screening Log\End Use Screening Log.xlsb"
    Windows("Copy of WW33 TEST .xlsm").Activate
    Range("G2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=VLOOKUP(RC[-4],'[End Use Screening Log.xlsb]EUS Log'!C1,1,0)"
    Range("G2").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("G2:G16")
    Range("G2:G16").Select
    Range("G1").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$Q$16").AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:=Array( _
        "4997466", "6392634", "9026175", "9362935", "9363654", "9369599", "9370171"), _
        Operator:=xlFilterValues
    Range("A2").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Rows("2:2").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Range("E15").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    Range("G2:G9").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range("Q2").Select
End Sub
```

However, I'm trying to automatize the process to do it just with one click.
I want to compare column `C` from `Excel 1` against column `A` from `Excel 2`.

I guess I'd need to do it with a VBA, because I've tried it recording the macro but doesn't work properly. 
Any ideas how to make this possible?

Maria

Comment: Can you post the code you've tried? What doesn't work about it, do you get errors (if so, what error at what line)?

Comment: Hi Bruce, I do a vlookup from column C against column A of the Excel 2. Example: *=VLOOKUP(C2,'[End Use Screening Log.xlsb]EUS Log'!$A:$A,1,0)) But it doesn't work for the automation process, because we change the data from Excel 1 every time we run the process, and the macro always delete the same amount of rows, and I need to delete only the one that are a match in that moment.

Comment: Could you edit your question with the macro code you produced (edit button is just below the tags at the bottom of the question).  You may find it faster to use the [Find](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Range.Find) method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a very crude code that might just work for your needs. I do not know what your worksheets look like and what your exact needs are but I just assumed you're just matching each cell of column C of Excel 1 to the values at column A of Excel 2, and if there is a match, the cell at row C of Excel 1 will be deleted.

Excel1 Workbook:

[image]

Excel2 Workbook:

[image]

Code:

```
Sub Macro1()

Start = 2

'Change path to your excel's file name
'This will open your 2nd excel file so that you won't have to open it evertime. Delete when not needed
Workbooks.Open ("C:\Users\Pops\Desktop\Excel2.xlsm")

'The deletion of the row will mess up with the For-Next loops so I included a GoTo so this is where it will end up
ReLoop:

'Counts how many rows are in your worksheets
Total_rows_Excel1 = Workbooks("Excel1.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Total_rows_Excel2 = Workbooks("Excel2.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

'Loops on all the rows on your worksheet
For i = Start To Total_rows_Excel1
    For j = 2 To Total_rows_Excel2
        If Workbooks("Excel1.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & i) = Workbooks("Excel2").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & j) Then
            Workbooks("Excel1").Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(i).Delete Shift:=xlUp 'Deletes the rows in Excel1 that have a match from Excel2
            Start = i 'This will let the loop to start at the last row it stopped when it loops again so it's less computationally taxing
            GoTo ReLoop
        End If
    Next j
Next i

End Sub
```

So at the click of a button, all the matches in Excel 1's column C to Excel 2's column A will be removed.

Result:

[image]

Comment: Hi Pherdindy! I really appreciate your help! I'll try it out Monday morning at work.

Comment: @DanielaBarrantes Glad to have helped